# Write a web browser for Android

Tags: java, android, browser, mozilla

This is hopefully an easy question to answer for someone familiar with Mozilla, but I'll be darned if I can find this info via Google searching.  I see a few apps, parental control software mostly, that replace the default web browser on Android OS.  They all look about the same and one of them (NetNanny) says they are using a Mozilla-based browser.  Is there a toolkit or something for creating custom web browsers (fairly easy?) from Mozilla?  Also, is it free for commercial use?

Edit: I'm looking for something like this I think, but this seems dated so I'm wondering if there are newer/better options:

http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/blackwood/webclient/

Just wondering what else is available, mostly Mozilla/Gecko based (since Firefox seems like a very nice browser), before I commit to using WebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a toolkit to create Gecko-based applications, it is called [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner). That's what Firefox Mobile is based on. However, there are no pre-built packages for Android, you would have to build it yourself from source. And I think that running XULRunner on Android is a rather tricky affair due to applications being in Java.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm not missing the point, I suspect I might be ;)

Most Android browsers are based on Webkit.

http://www.webkit.org/

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/package-summary.html

Comment: I'll edit my question, but you pointed out something to help me write it better.  I guess what I'm looking for is probably Gecko and maybe not Mozilla... like WebKit is to WebView.  I might end up using WebView after all, but I'd like to know about any Mozilla/Gecko options before I commit to WebKit/WebView.

Comment: Not really on-topic of my original question, so posting this as a comment instead.  Is there a Java version of WebKit?  I checked that site but only see C/C++ projects.  I don't think WebView will work for me because then I'm limited to the events it exposes, and I'm pretty sure I'll want more control, like maybe handling the data stream itself.

Comment: @eselk: See [developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) - WebKit is included in Android and can be used by applications.